# laravel elixir version / hash a file not working

Tags: gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I am trying out laravel elixir and managed to get a minified `all.css` in `public/css/all.css`. When I try to version it, the command runs without error, but I can't find the versioned file. It seems as if nothing is happening. I tried different paths like `public/css/all.css`, but no success. What could it be else, that I am doing wrong?

this is gulpfile.js command:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.version('css/all.css');
});
```

**solved:** the versioned file appears in `public/build/css`

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to worry about the path or name of the generated file, and referencing the versioned file with `elixir('css/all.css')` inside your view.